# Proper teatment of lists of word tokens in a df for clustering - advice needed

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, tokenize

I have been provided with tokenized text that has been previously generated. I would like to keep these tokens and use them in my analysis. For each item of interest, there are multiple lists of tokens for various text attributes of the item organized in a dataframe. Here is an example of one such item taken from the dataframe:

> ingredient_tokens    [12698, 11125, 4465, 29487, 6444, 15000, 27043...
> steps_tokens         [40480, 40482, 8263, 280, 7420, 11125, 556, 64...
> techniques           [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
> ingredient_ids                                 [648, 3355, 7501, 4253]

Each item has a different length of ingredient_tokens, steps_tokens, and ingredient_ids.

I am wondering how to make this data usable. I would like to cluster the data, but I cannot use a dataframe filled with lists. There is additional data cleaning required. I am thinking of encoding, for example, ingredient_ids so that the dataframe would contain new columns (648,3355,7501,4353) with 1's and 0's for ingredients used and not used. However, I am having a hard time making this transformation (see below). I would do this for the other features as well.

However, there are two issues:

1. Wouldn't I lose some of the meaning preserved in the embeddings if I treat them just like generic feature names?
2. How do I technically go about doing this encoding? I am getting tripped up on this, as the list input is not standard. I've tried using MultiLabelBinarizer but it reduces the data to individual numbers and ignores the list structure.

I would really appreciate advice on how to make this data usable. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what `ingredient_tokens` actually stands for. :/ Why is `techniques` binary? Are there more rows?

Comment: Hello, this data was cleaned by someone else. It appears that one-hot-encoding was likely used to generate the techniques lists while the other lists were generated by tokenizing text using the GPT subword tokenizer. Also, yes there are many more rows like this.